# Questions related to the "strong" property in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

Recently, I have been working with obj-c for iOS development, and have been perplexed by the "strong" property that can be attached to variables in classes.

1) First and foremost, in a practical sense, what exactly does "strong" do?

2) I've noticed when constructing several obj-c classes that "strong" is typically typed in a @property context (ie `@property (strong) UIImage *pic1, *pic2;`) if one didn't want to declare a variable with the property/synthesize setup, is it possible to give such a variable the "strong" attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strong reference takes ownership of an object.

When you set a strong property, the passed object is retained by the property owner, e.g. `[theViewController setString:aString];` causes `theViewController` to take ownership of `aString`. That object will be released when the property is set to something else.

There's a [ownership qualifier](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership), `__strong`, which makes a variable behave the way I've described above. It is the default for any object variable -- `NSArray * a;` is a strong reference, equivalent to `__strong NSArray * a;`. The one difference is that the object will be released not just when the variable is re-set, but when it goes out of scope, as at the end of a method:

```
- (void)activate {
    NSArray * a = [NSArray array];
    // a is __strong by default, takes ownership

} // a is going out of scope. To prevent a leak, ARC releases the array
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Strong is a the ARC replacement for retain. Basically, it means that when assigning a value to this property, such as `[foo setBar: someValue]`, the instance variable that backs the property `bar` will increment the retain count on the parameter `someValue` passed to `setBar`.

2) I think what you are referring to is the use of the `__strong` prefix, so yes.